# How to specify Dapr component locations with Sidekick?

Tags: .net-6.0, dapr, dapr-sidekick

I'm trying to get started with Sidekick for Dapr, and am having trouble telling Sidekick where the dapr components are.

By default it's going to %USERPROFILE%.dapr\components, but I'd rather it go to a folder local to the solution.

Looking at the code it appears that adding the following to the appsettings.json should work, but it isn't picked up.

```
 "DaprSidekick": {
    "RuntimeDirectory": "dapr",
    "ComponentsDirectory": "C:\\Dev\\DaprPOC\\components",
  }
```

However the components folder invariably becomes `%USERPROFILE%\.dapr\components`

Any help on how I specify the component locations with Sidekick?

Answer (score 0):

When you set `"RuntimeDirectory": "dapr"` Sidekick will automatically look for component files in the `dapr/components` subdirectory in your solution. Try removing the `ComponentsDirectory` entry so it returns to defaults, and try a directory structure like this:

```
|-- MyProject
|   |-- MyProject.csproj
|   |-- dapr
|   |   |-- config.yaml
|   |   |-- components
|   |   |   |-- my_component.yaml
```

The Dapr Sidecar should then load `my_component.yaml`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also manually add the components directory in the dependency injection:

```
   services.AddDaprSidekick(configuration, p => p.Sidecar = 
        new DaprSidecarOptions() { AppId = "daprservice", ComponentsDirectory = "C:\\Dev\\DaprPOC\\components" });
```